# Stamp Problem Homework

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that you have a large supply of $3$ and $7$ cent stamps. Write a recurrence relation and initial conditions for the number $S_n$ of different ways in which n cents worth of stamps can be attached to an envelope if the order in which the stamps are attached does matter.

Comment: What is the trouble?

Comment: I know you have to set the initial conditions so that S0 = 3, and S1 = 7. But I do not know how to set up the equation after that.

Comment: Let us set up the reverse recurrence scheme: $S_{n}=S_{n-7}+S_{n-3}$. Your set up makes little sense as $0,1$ cents has no choice at all - they are impossible.

Comment: Note: order does not matter.  Hence e.g. $S_{10}=1 \neq 2=S_3+S_7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordered case, as previously noted, satisfies the recurrence $$S_{\mathrm{ord}}(n)=S_{\mathrm{ord}}(n-3)+S_{\mathrm{ord}}(n-7).$$

For the unordered case, I give the following hint:

*Hint* (since this is flagged as homework): We can adjust this recurrence to account for the "order is not important" by adding in a correction term to account for overcounting.  So, we have $$S(n)=S(n-3)+S(n-7)-[???].$$  There's quite an elegant reason for this, and I don't want to spoil this for you.

The initial conditions are merely bookkeeping (they can be counted by hand, once you know the depth of the recurrence).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put $n$ cents worth of stamps, you can either put one $7$ cent stamp and $n-7$ cents worth of stamps (i.e. $S_{n-7}$), provided that $n \geq 7$, or one $3$ cent stamp and $n-3$ cents worth of stamps (i.e. $S_{n-3}$), provided that $n \geq 3$.
As far as initial conditions are concerned, you just have to analyse what is going on for $n < 7$, which should be fairly easy.

Comment: So for all n>= 7, Sn = 7+S(n-7) and for all n>=3, Sn = 3+S(n-3)?

How would that work for n= 4? You can't have use a 3 cent stamp and then have .01$ of another.

Comment: Actually, I did not see the part where you say that the order does not matter. However, for the ordered case, the relation would be for $n \geq 7, S_n = S_{n-7} + S_{n-3}$.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original question. Order does matter

Comment: No, $S(n) = S(n-3) + S(n-7)$ for $n\ge 7$. Smaller than that you do by hand. Note however that $S(0)=1$. And I guess this is ordered, because the choice in the recursion (take 3 or 7) fixes the value of the first stamp, etc.

Comment: Can you work out why this is true?

Comment: @MKZ: Choosing an ordered sequence is the same as choosing the first element, and then choosing the rest. The thing is, here, you want to count the sequences of 3 and 7's that add up to $n$, so once you chose the first element $k$, you need to count the sequences that add up to $n-k$. Is it clearer ?